# Ember-data computed property on an async relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have some models set up with async relationships, e.g.:

```
User = DS.Model({
    postsApproved: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true, inverse: 'approved'})
})

Post = DS.Model({
    approver: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true, inverse: 'postsApproved'})
})
```

In a controller, I have a property on the post, `isApproved`, which simply checks if `approver` is set.  I expect that this should work:

```
isApproved: function() {
    return !Ember.isNone(this.get('approver'));
}
```

But that always returns true, and if I inspect the data I see that it is because `this.get('approver')` returns a promise.  This works:

```
isApproved: function() {
    return !Ember.isNone(this.get('approver.content'));
}
```

But using `content` seems to me to be messing around with the internals a bit too much.  Is this the right way to do it, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, testing for `this.get('approver.content')` is not correct, as the element may actually have an associated `approver`, but it may not be loaded yet.

Try to load the related model on the route:

```
// route.js
model: function(params) {
   return this.store.find('post', params.post_id).then(function(post) {
     return Ember.RSVP.hash({
       post: post,
       approver: post.get('approver')
     });
   });
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model.post);
  controller.set('approver', model.approver);
},

// controller.js
isApproved: function() {
    return !Ember.isNone(this.get('approver'));
}.property('approver')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't seem to stop ember returning the promise rather than the value, even though the promise is fulfilled.  By inspecting it, I can see that when `isApproved` runs, the promise is fulfilled, but `this.get('approver')` returns a promise which has `{content: null, isFulfilled: true}`, but which itself is not `null`.

Comment: try adding `approver: null` to the controller definition, (or maybe a different name to differentiate from the async approver on the model)